# How do I implement a Decorator class of abstract class with no default constructor?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator

I am trying to make an decorator class, but I am getting an error "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'conversation'of Call.Call(Conversation)

Normally you would instantiate a Conversation object and then instantiate a new Call object with reference to that Conversation

example:  Call _call = new Call(_conversation);

```
public abstract class CallDecorator : Call
{
    public CallDecorator(Call aCall)
    {

    }
```

The error is on the decorator.

Context: The Conversation and the Call objects are part of the Microsoft.rtc.collaboration SDK for Lync. The conversation has no parameterless constructor, but should be instantiated with new Conversation(_endpoint)

Maybe some other pattern would apply

Comment: You always need to call a constructor from the base class. You could just keep aCall  in a property, instead of trying to use it as a base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the constructor what it wants.  Assuming the conversation object is exposed on the call.

```
public abstract class CallDecorator : Call
{
    public CallDecorator(Call aCall):base(aCall.Conversation)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Wow dbugger. That is a fast response. Thank you. I always want to give it what it wants. I was just not clear to me what it wanted.